# Redis with Java / Jedis Library Cold Standby Server

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I am looking for a solution using Java and Redis (currently using the Jedis library) of having a cold standby redis server. I am looking for an intermediate solution to a single server, and a cluster of servers. Specifically, I want to have two servers setup, each standalone, and have my application only use the first Redis server if it is available, and fail over to the second server, only if the first server is not available - a standard cold standby scenario - no replication.

The current connection factory is setup as

public JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();

```
    redisConnectionFactory.setHostName(redisUrl);
    redisConnectionFactory.setPort(redisPort);
    redisConnectionFactory.setDatabase(redisDbIndex);
    return redisConnectionFactory;
}
```

where redisUrl resolves to something like 'my-redis-server.some-domain.com'. I would like to be able to specify the redis host name something like 'my-redis-server-1.some-domain.com,my-redis-server-2.some-domain.com' and have the second server used as the cold standby.